# Save html web form as draft

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone give me some guide or point me a way, how can I save a html web form which is partially filled as draft, then it can be reloaded later allowing user to continue fill in all information and subsequently submit it?

I am working on a web form to gather some information input by user, using PHP and MySQL. Have no clue on this. Any guidance will be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save the information they write into your database, but set it as not published.

You can do this by creating a `boolean` or `bit` field called published in the database table.

When they save as a draft, mark published as false or 0.

Then when they finish it you can mark it as true or 1.

When you are displaying the finished forms, do a `SELECT * FROM forms WHERE published = 1` and `SELECT * FROM forms WHERE published = 0` to get the ones that are not finished.

Comment: Thank you for the method by enable a boolean check on publish/unpublished data suggested. 1 question, if the user reload the partially complete web form, can all the data be called out from the database into the specific fields of the form as what they entered previously while enabling incomplete field accessible by user? Because I will need to preserve the look and arrangement of the web form exactly as when user 'save' it.

Comment: Yep, you just need to design your database to allow that.  The easiest is to make a 1 to 1 correspondence between your form and the database table.  So every item in the form has its own field.  Then you can just save the data to those fields and load them up again when they come back.

Comment: I think I got the idea, thank you very much for the guidance. I will try it out right away!

Comment: Have you solved this? cus I have to do this and am struggling HARD...edit: the draft also has to be accessible by multiple people